# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool Yii2 PHP8.2

Tags: yii, yii2, php-8.2

The following code produces the mentioned error.
What is the fix for PHP 8.2?

PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

```
In /var/www/html/atmtest/frontend/modules/atm/controllers/TwmgdtreportController.php 
at line 132

        $date = $model->tr_date;
 
        //$drID = Dailyroutine::find()->select('dr_id')->where(['dr_date' => $date, 
        //'dr_empid' => $user])->column();
 
        $post = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM dailyroutine WHERE 
        dr_date=:dr_date AND dr_empid=:dr_empid')
           ->bindValue(':dr_date', $date)
           ->bindValue(':dr_empid', $user)
           ->queryOne();
 
           $drID = $post['dr_id'];

        //print(json_encode($dr));
        //die();
```

Comment: Method `queryOne()` can return `false` when the query returns empty result. Obviously, you can't access `['dr_id']` on `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix

```
if(is_array($post)){
   $drID = $post['dr_id'];
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).